# Cambiar mysqli a PDO al insertar datos en DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Siempre me han recomendado `PDO` sobre `MySQLI`, por lo que me gustaría cambiar mi conexión a la hora de insertar datos en mi `DB`.
Ya estoy utilizando `PDO` para mostrar los datos al cliente.

He utilizado `PDO` de la siguiente forma, me inserta los datos correctamente pero me da **else** en:

`if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE)`

```html
<?php
$conn = null;
  $host = '*******';
  $db =   '*******';
  $user = '*******';
  $pwd =  '*******';
try {
      $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }


  $sql = "INSERT INTO avisos (.......) VALUES (...........)";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
   window.location='https://*******';
   </script>";
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }

  $conn->close();
}
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
      exit;
  }
  return $conn;
 

?>
```

Comment: No soy un experto, pero que tenga entendido PDO va mas lento... aunque es mas legible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo utilizo así:

```
$statement = "INSERT INTO ...";
$statement = $connection->prepare($statement);
$statement->execute($parameters);
return $statement->rowCount();
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas son erróneas en tu código, se nota que quedan en él reminiscencias de `mysqli`:

1. PDO no tiene una propiedad `connect_error`. Además, los errores de conexión se manejan en el `catch`, no  por casualidad conectas dentro de un `try`
2. Para consultas del tipo `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` convendría más bien recuperar la cantidad de filas afectadas usando [`rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) en vez de revisar lo que devuelve `query`, que es un objeto PDOStatement <sub>[[ver el apartado **Valores devueltos** en la doc](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.query.php)]</sub>.
3. PDO no tiene una propiedad `error`. Los errores se recogen mediante el método [`errorInfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) en cual, OJO, devuelve un array. Y, OJO, tanto la conexión como el statement tienen ese método. Aquí se llama el método del statement.

Aplicando lo dicho, tu código podría quedar así:

```
<?php
    $conn = null;
    $host = '*******';
    $db =   '*******';
    $user = '*******';
    $pwd =  '*******';
    try {
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO avisos (.......) VALUES (...........)";
            if ( $stmt = $conn->query($sql) ) {

                $info = sprintf( "Se insertaron %d filas",$stmt->rowCount() );
                #Usar $info en la salida si quieres
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        window.location='https://*******';
                      </script>";
            } else {
                # errorInfo() devuelve un array y en el mensaje está en el índice 2
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $stmt->errorInfo()[2];
            }

            $conn->close();
    }
      catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    } 

?>
```

He corregido otras cosas como quitar el `return` del objeto conexión. No tiene sentido, además, la cierras dentro del `try`. He quitado las llamadas a propiedades que no existen. Y, trata de evitar `exit()` y `die()`. Es mejor controlar el código y devolver variables con la información cuando sea necesario.